# Compiler Error C2228 in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, webrtc

I'm trying to compile the webrtc code in visual studio and have run up against this error (from type_traits.h). The code is:

```
// Determines if the given class has zero-argument .data() and .size() methods
// whose return values are convertible to T* and size_t, respectively.
template <typename DS, typename T>
class HasDataAndSize {
 private:
     template <
     typename C,
     typename std::enable_if<
     std::is_convertible<decltype(std::declval<C>().data()), T*>::value &&
     std::is_convertible<decltype(std::declval<C>().size()), std::size_t>::value>::type* = nullptr>
  static int Test(int);

  template <typename>
  static char Test(...);

 public:
  static constexpr bool value = std::is_same<decltype(Test<DS>(0)), int>::value;
};
```

The error is:

Error   C2228   left of '.data' must have class/struct/union

- How do I re-write this template so it compiles with the visual studio 2015 compiler?

Answer (score 0):

Updating visual studio 2015 to update 3 resolved this issue.